# Extract all data from webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

I try to extract all the data, starting at `<html>` to `</html>`, from a webpage. The following code does work with a *.html* file, but not with a html website.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("http://www.imdb.com", "UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.text());
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just google a combination of "JSoup" and "scraping" or "spider". Plenty of tutorials around.

Comment: Are you implying that I haven't tried to search for a solution? Because if that is the case then I am going to tell you that I have searched for a while. I never you this website instantly, but I really could not find it anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather use `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com").get();` for a remote website.

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc;
try {

    // need http protocol
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com").get();

    // get page title
    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);

    // get all links
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {

        // get the value from href attribute
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Source : mkyong.com